# ruby to unjumble words

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, permutation

I am trying to write a ruby script that unscrambles permuted words, generates all the permutations, and searches for the word in a txt directory. I'm running into problems.

This is a simple outline of what I have.

```
print "Enter Permuted Word:"
words = STDIN.gets.chomp


a = to_array(s)
print a, "\n"


perms = a.permutation(3).to_a.collect do |perm|
perm.join
end
print perms, "\n"

file = file.open("words.txt", "r")
file.read.each_line do |line|
fields = line.chomp.split(",")
words_un = fields[1]
end
file.close
```

the txt file looks something like this

```
words_un
Aarhus
Aaron
Ababa
aback
abaft
abandon
abandoned
abandoning
abandonment
abandons
abase
...
Zulus
Zurich
```

Comment: What does Ruby on Rails have to do with the question? Seems like this is pure Ruby.

Comment: Break it down a little, don't present the whole script at once, because it is not at all clear what your question is when you do that. At what point does the script stop doing what you want it to do? Ask a question just about that - just what you want that bit to do, what your current code is, what the input and expected output should be. Once that is sorted, move on with the script, and if you get stuck again, ask next question . . .

Comment: @Neil, I believe the asker has a dictionary of words and a string, and simply wants to know if there is a permutation of the characters of the string that forms a word in the dictionary. user3637905, you might consider doing an edit to add some similar words to clarify.  Feel free to borrow any of mine.  I found it an interesting question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is `to_array`? What is `s`?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland: I understand what the OP was trying to do. However, the point for me is to help the OP get past specific blocks, not solve their coding project for them. It is not clear where the OP is struggling with Ruby syntax versus algorithm design. I think this is in fact 2 or 3 separate questions.

Comment: There are now three votes to close your question.  If you want it to survive, you need to edit to clarify, without delay.

Comment: @Neil, yes, I agree.  The fact that the OP seems to have vanished doesn't help.  It's frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `dict` is an array of strings that your dictionary and `scrambled` is a scrambled word (a string).  Considering all permutations of `scrambled` or (far worse) the elements of `dist` would be highly inefficient.  Suppose, for example, the first two letters of one scrambled permutation were `qz`.  If there were no element (word) in `dict` that begins `qz`, there would be no point in considering any of the permutations of `scrambled` that begin `qz`.

**Data Structures**

Suppose this were our dictionary.

```
dict = ["dog", "cat", "cow", "emu", "cod", "cobra"]
```

If we just want to see if a few scrambled words were in the dictionary, we could do this for each:

```
   r = 'mue'.split('').permutation(3).find { |w| dict.include?(w.join) }     
     #=> ["e", "m", "u"]
   r.any? ? r.join('') : nil
     #=> "emu"

   r = 'nvwls'.split('').permutation(3).find { |w| dict.include?(w.join) }     
     #=> nil
```

The more interesting question is how to do this in a more efficient way, for checking large numbers of posssilby-longish words that have many permutations.

The first step is to reorganize the dictionary to make lookups for efficient.  I am not the best person to suggest how that be done, as I am not familiar with that (or any other) branch of computer science.  Here is one way, using a multi-level hash:

```
dh = { "c"=>{ "a"=>{ "t"=>nil },
              "o"=>{ "b"=>{ "r"=>{ "a"=>nil } }, "w"=>nil, "d"=>nil } },
       "d"=>{ "o"=>{ "g"=>nil } },
       "e"=>{ "m"=>{ "u"=>nil } } }
```

`dh["c"]` "contains" all words that begin with "c"; `dh["c"]["a"]` contains all words that begin with "ca", and so on.  `dh["c"]["a"]["t"] => nil` signifies that `dh["c"]["a"]["t"].join('') => 'cat'` is one of the words in the dictionary.  I will assume that you have `dh`.  If you would like suggestions on how to construct `dh` from `dict`, perhaps you could ask that as a separate question.

**Code**

Here is a (recursive) method that could be used to see if any of the unscramblings of `scrambled` are contained in `dict`.  (It would not be difficult to modify this to compile a list of all permutations that are found in `dict`, but that is not the problem I've addressed.)  This method is called with `look_up(dh, scrambled)`.

```
def look_up(dh, left, used = '')
  left.size.times do |i|
    left_copy = left.dup
    e = left_copy[i]
    left_copy[i] = ''
    v = dh[e]
    case v
    when nil
      (return used + e) if left_copy.empty?
    when Hash
      word = look_up(v, left_copy, used + e)
      return word if word
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

**Example**

```
look_up(dh, "owc")         #=> "cow"
look_up(dh, "mue")         #=> "emu"
look_up(dh, "bocar")       #=> "cobra"
look_up(dh, "esuomhcruhc") #=> nil
```

**Explanation**

Suppose `dh` is as above and `scrambled => "owc"`.  Then

```
left = "owc"
used = ''

left.size              #=> 3
enum = left.size.times #=> #<Enumerator: 3:times>
```

We can convert `enum` to an array to see what it will be passing to its block:

```
enum.to_a              #=> [0, 1, 2]
```

Initially, the block variable `i` is set to `0` and

```
left_copy = left.dup  #=> "owc"
e = left_copy[i]      #=> left_copy[0] => "o"
left_copy[i] = ''     #left_copy[i] = '' 
left_copy             #=> "wc"
v = dh[e]             #=> v = dh[0] => nil
```

`dh[0] => nil`, combined with `left_copy.empty? => false`, means there are no words in the dictionary beginning with 'o', so we return to the top of the loop and set `i => 1` and consider words beginning with `'o'`:

```
left_copy = left.dup  #=> "owc"
e = left_copy[i]      #=> left_copy[1] => "w"
left_copy[i] = ''     #=> left_copy[1] = ''
left_copy             #=> "oc"
v = dh[e]             #=> v = dh[1] => nil
```

There are no words in the dictionary beginning with `'w'`, so we loop again with `i => 2`,

```
searching for words in the dictionary beginning with `'c'`:

e = left_copy[2]      #=> "c"
left_copy[2] = ''     #=> left_copy[2] = ''
left_copy             #=> "ow"
v = dh[2]             #=> {"a"=>{"t"=>nil},
                      #    "o"=>{"b"=>{"r"=>{"a"=>nil}}, "w"=>nil, "d"=>nil}}
```

This shows that there are words in the dictionary beginning ``` 'ca`` and ```'co'`.

As `v` is a hash, we call the method recursively

```
word = look_up(v, left_copy, used + e)
  #    look_up({"a"=>{"t"=>nil},
  #             "o"=>{"b"=>{"r"=>{"a"=>nil}}, "w"=>nil, "d"=>nil}},
  #             "ow",
  #             "c")
```

Calculations proceed similarly for additional letters.  When it is found that there are words in the dictionary for the string `"co"` represented by:

```
{ "b"=>{ "r"=>{ "a"=>nil } }, "w"=>nil, "d"=>nil }
```

we conclude that, since this hash contains `"w"=>nil`, that `"cow"` is in the dictionary, so we return `'cow'` up the recursive chain and are finished.